# Set data-quantity attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function quantChange() {
d = document.getElementById("dropdown5").value;
alert(d);
document.getElementbyId("5").setAttribute('data-quantity',d);

}
```

The alert works fine. But the element I'm trying to set the attribute for remains unchanged. I've tried it with the attribute already on the element as well as not on the element.

Here is the element I'm trying to modify:

`<a href="/shop/weekly-meal-plans/?add-to-cart=5" rel="nofollow" id="5" data-quantity="0" data-product_id="5">Add to Plan</a>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to jquery as well. Jquery just has some issues depending on your wordpress install so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: That was only on my copy paste because I pasted from chrome inspection. Fixed. That's not the issue.

Comment: There are errors all over, getElementById is written in three different ways in your code?

Comment: My god. that was it. I'm taking a break. Sorry for wasting everyone's time on this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks us to find a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case is important - it should be `getElementById` not `ID`.  Check your browser's error console for the corresponding error.

Comment: Fixed. That wasn't it though.

Comment: You said you fixed it, but the fix is still wrong - `by` is lowercase.

Comment: Nope, there's also `getElementbyId` with lowercase `b` etc

Comment: Right just saw that. I'm taking a break. That was dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see typo here.

   `getElementById`
2. You should not use IDs as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip although I stripped a bunch of php and text out of there just for this example so I don't normally do that.